# windows 10 latency - different results performance monitor vs latencymon

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, latency

I tried to solve the latency issue myself by updating drivers etc.  tried all the methods/varients of drivers using the easydriver update tool, but latency is still continuing.

I have used the latencymon and the windows performance monitor tool too, but unable to figure out the issue.  Could you please help me out.  High dpc is showing at ntoskrnl., next to it is vsdatant (zone alarm I suppose); way behind them is nvlddmkm (number is small so not an issue I think).

But according to latency mon -the higest execution time is for tcpip and ndis.sys.  So not able to figure out what the cause is

System configuration:
Windows 10
AMD phenom 2 X4 945
Gigabyte GT 730 - 2GB DDR5
Mb = M5A78L M Plus usb3

EDIT:
I have just now tested with USB LAN adapter, to my surprise even this is having the same issue.  The issue is coming only when I make use of internet.

[Performance Analyzer screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7M0x.png)

Complete performance analyzer file (etl): [googledrive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8H-FGaZBtkNTFR2NVBxbElvX3c) or [fileuploads](https://ufile.io/2690d)

[Latencymon pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilkPi.png)

Latencymon result:

---

CONCLUSION

---

Your system appears to be having trouble handling real-time audio and other tasks. You are likely to experience buffer underruns appearing as drop outs, clicks or pops. One or more DPC routines that belong to a driver running in your system appear to be executing for too long. Also one or more ISR routines that belong to a driver running in your system appear to be executing for too long. At least one detected problem appears to be network related. In case you are using a WLAN adapter, try disabling it to get better results. One problem may be related to power management, disable CPU throttling settings in Control Panel and BIOS setup. Check for BIOS updates. 
LatencyMon has been analyzing your system for  0:01:49  (h:mm:ss) on all processors.

---

SYSTEM INFORMATION

---

Computer name:                                        DESKTOP-B73A5II
OS version:                                           Windows 10 , 10.0, build: 14393 (x64)
Hardware:                                             ASUSTeK Computer INC., M5A78L-M PLUS/USB3
CPU:                                                  AuthenticAMD AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 945 Processor
Logical processors:                                   4
Processor groups:                                     1
RAM:                                                  6142 MB total

---

CPU SPEED

---

Reported CPU speed:                                   3014 MHz

Note: reported execution times may be calculated based on a fixed reported CPU speed. Disable variable speed settings like Intel Speed Step and AMD Cool N Quiet in the BIOS setup for more accurate results.

---

MEASURED INTERRUPT TO USER PROCESS LATENCIES

---

The interrupt to process latency reflects the measured interval that a usermode process needed to respond to a hardware request from the moment the interrupt service routine started execution. This includes the scheduling and execution of a DPC routine, the signaling of an event and the waking up of a usermode thread from an idle wait state in response to that event.

Highest measured interrupt to process latency (µs):   64670.563050
Average measured interrupt to process latency (µs):   63.193641

Highest measured interrupt to DPC latency (µs):       44998.470896
Average measured interrupt to DPC latency (µs):       41.070269

---

REPORTED ISRs

---

Interrupt service routines are routines installed by the OS and device drivers that execute in response to a hardware interrupt signal.

Highest ISR routine execution time (µs):              4771.277704
Driver with highest ISR routine execution time:       dxgkrnl.sys - DirectX Graphics Kernel, Microsoft Corporation

Highest reported total ISR routine time (%):          0.279491
Driver with highest ISR total time:                   dxgkrnl.sys - DirectX Graphics Kernel, Microsoft Corporation

Total time spent in ISRs (%)                          0.422111

ISR count (execution time <250 µs):                   186495
ISR count (execution time 250-500 µs):                0
ISR count (execution time 500-999 µs):                33
ISR count (execution time 1000-1999 µs):              8
ISR count (execution time 2000-3999 µs):              13
ISR count (execution time >=4000 µs):                 0

---

REPORTED DPCs

---

DPC routines are part of the interrupt servicing dispatch mechanism and disable the possibility for a process to utilize the CPU while it is interrupted until the DPC has finished execution.

Highest DPC routine execution time (µs):              46762.675182
Driver with highest DPC routine execution time:       tcpip.sys - TCP/IP Driver, Microsoft Corporation

Highest reported total DPC routine time (%):          3.264468
Driver with highest DPC total execution time:         tcpip.sys - TCP/IP Driver, Microsoft Corporation

Total time spent in DPCs (%)                          5.937386

DPC count (execution time <250 µs):                   295670
DPC count (execution time 250-500 µs):                0
DPC count (execution time 500-999 µs):                145
DPC count (execution time 1000-1999 µs):              183
DPC count (execution time 2000-3999 µs):              283
DPC count (execution time >=4000 µs):                 0

---

REPORTED HARD PAGEFAULTS

---

Hard pagefaults are events that get triggered by making use of virtual memory that is not resident in RAM but backed by a memory mapped file on disk. The process of resolving the hard pagefault requires reading in the memory from disk while the process is interrupted and blocked from execution.

NOTE: some processes were hit by hard pagefaults. If these were programs producing audio, they are likely to interrupt the audio stream resulting in dropouts, clicks and pops. Check the Processes tab to see which programs were hit.

Process with highest pagefault count:                 firefox.exe

Total number of hard pagefaults                       94
Hard pagefault count of hardest hit process:          44
Highest hard pagefault resolution time (µs):          11427.575315
Total time spent in hard pagefaults (%):              0.008947
Number of processes hit:                              6

---

PER CPU DATA

---

CPU 0 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       9.640117
CPU 0 ISR highest execution time (µs):                4771.277704
CPU 0 ISR total execution time (s):                   1.834405
CPU 0 ISR count:                                      185655
CPU 0 DPC highest execution time (µs):                44991.028202
CPU 0 DPC total execution time (s):                   6.938846
CPU 0 DPC count:                                      263535

---

CPU 1 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       5.783185
CPU 1 ISR highest execution time (µs):                239.634373
CPU 1 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.007476
CPU 1 ISR count:                                      892
CPU 1 DPC highest execution time (µs):                45147.389847
CPU 1 DPC total execution time (s):                   5.313124
CPU 1 DPC count:                                      11453

---

CPU 2 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       9.321844
CPU 2 ISR highest execution time (µs):                13.264101
CPU 2 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.000109
CPU 2 ISR count:                                      12
CPU 2 DPC highest execution time (µs):                46762.675182
CPU 2 DPC total execution time (s):                   8.873685
CPU 2 DPC count:                                      12276

---

CPU 3 Interrupt cycle time (s):                       5.011146
CPU 3 ISR highest execution time (µs):                0.0
CPU 3 ISR total execution time (s):                   0.0
CPU 3 ISR count:                                      0
CPU 3 DPC highest execution time (µs):                46649.379894
CPU 3 DPC total execution time (s):                   4.783671
CPU 3 DPC count:                                      10865

---

Comment: Thank you for moving the question from  serverfault to superuser.  I was unaware of this meta.

Comment: Confused by your question don't see anything to connect it to network latency

Comment: The latency is not in network - there is a CPU lag, CPU going about 30-50% some times crashing audio etc... I removed Zone alarm and it is working fine now, I tried the WFN it is not good - hence went for COMODO for now it seems to be stable and doing good.

Comment: CPU being pegged and there being high percentage of interrupts isn't really called latency.

Comment: @Ramhound - sorry, I said it as latency as this is what commented in summary by latencymon - 'Highest measured interrupt to process latency'

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit - it was zone alarm. Uninstalled and there is no latency.  I reinstalled it again - this time latency is controlled.
When zone alarm was uninstalled the system interrupts was max at 1% only. Re-installed and system interrupts rose to 3% approx.